# How can I get a path to the BaseTheme resources from a derived theme in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

In my Orchard project I have a BaseTheme and a few themes that are derived from it.

In my BaseTheme I have a folder `/Styles/Images`. I need to get a path to that folder in a JavaScript variable in order to pass it to UI components. In order to do that there is a view in the BaseTheme that is shared among all derived themes. In this view I have a piece of JavaScript code that gets the path:

```
var pathToImages = '@Url.Content(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme, "/Styles/Images/"))';
```

The problem is it only gets the right path when the view is rendered from the context of the BaseTheme.
Each derived theme that renders this view gets an incorrect path, because the code that gets it explicitly says WorkContext.CurrentTheme (and thus this path is relative to the derived theme).

How can I get a path to resources that sit in the BaseTheme from a view that sits in the BaseTheme but is rendered from a derived theme?

Comment: Not sure why you'd have to do that from Javascript, but did you try to not use ThemePath at all but instead to use the application relative path of the theme explicitly?

Comment: It's not "from" JavaScript it's from ASP.NET/Orchard to JavaScript. As I said I need to get a path to a folder in a variable in JavaScript. What do you mean by the application relative path of the theme?

Comment: Don't play on words. You are providing the value from your server code to your script. I mean ```Url.Content("~/Themes/NameOfTheBaseTheme/Styles/Images")```

Comment: That worked, thanks! If one can use the application relative path what is the purpose of Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme then?

Comment: If you have a base theme with your company logo and you create a theme for a client based on that, using theme path lets you easily replace the logo in the inheriting theme and not have to mess with files. I guess. Maybe

Comment: It's slightly cleaner because you can actually copy that code from one theme to another without modification, but it doesn't work for derived themes. Will copy as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the application-relative path to the resource instead:

```
@Url.Content("~/Themes/NameOfTheBaseTheme/Styles/Images")
```